# How to create a dynamic listbox based on the values written on the combobox using VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Basically, the function of the comboboxes will be similar to a filter criteria. So every time I change the value of the combobox, the `AfterUpdate` event will run a code that should update the listbox to only contain values that match that criteria.

My plan was to use `Autofilter` to actually do this then use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to set the rowsource.

Initial Code Idea:

```
Private Sub cbxSupplier_AfterUpdate()
Dim Suppler_col As Long
    Supplier_col = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("SUPPLIER").Index
    filterRangeFoilProfile.AutoFilter Field:=Supplier_col, Criteria1:=cbxSupplier.Text
    lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End Sub
```

However, my issue is that the `Rowsource` method uses a string assuming an excel formula reference such as the following: `lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource ="'Foil Profile'!A1:K5"` and you cannot use VBA language to assign the values of the rowsource method.

The issue here is that even the values in between the filtered range will be used in the `Rowsource`. The work around here is to copy in a "Help worksheet" the visible cells of a table only by using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` instead, but my concern is that i'll need to clear the entire help worksheet in the `After Update` event for each time a combobox's value was changed.

Can I ask if there is any faster/easier/more efficient way to actually do this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show just filtered rows in my userform listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948329/how-to-show-just-filtered-rows-in-my-userform-listbox)

Comment: @PEH thanks for the link although I came to realize that the `For-each-next` loop used in the example loops through all the cells in the range. It worked in the example in the post due to the fact that he only had a single column, `D`, to loop through. But in my case it will loop `number of rows` x `number of columns` times I believe. How do I use the `for-each-next` loop with my case?

Comment: Well, you need one loop to loop through your visible rows, and inside that loop anther loop, that loops through the columns of each row. That's a common issue and there are hundreds of examples for that: [One here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837959/loop-through-rows-and-columns-excel-macro-vba) you will find others on Google.

Comment: I think this works `For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows` Thanks I rarely use `For-Each-Next` It took me a long time to figure out it was looping through all the cells rather than the rows