# How can I update a listbox with AutoFilter data?

Tags: excel, vba, search, listbox, userform

I have a userform which lists information from a worksheet in a listbox.
I have added a search tool which filters by keywords entered using AutoFilter.
How can I then display the filtered worksheet in the listbox?

I've been playing around with SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) but I can't seem to get it to work, it says permission denied.

Here is my current code to search the worksheet and filter the data.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=txtKeywords.Value
End Sub
```

My aim is to have the data displayed in this listbox, so I can then add functions for deleting the data from the worksheet.

Comment: are you populating your listbox as part of initialize code?  when you load your userform, are you opening as modeless?  you should be able to provide a new array to the listbox right after your sort (can do it several ways)

Comment: also, need to know more about your data... are there duplicate values in the listbox, or will you be needing to find unique values?

Comment: also, have you seen this post, [How to show just filtered rows in my userform listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948329/how-to-show-just-filtered-rows-in-my-userform-listbox)